# Facing Storage Permission Issues in Android 10 alone to store data

Tags: android, scoped-storage

Hi i have a recording application which stores the recordings in the Custom folder where user opts for but starting from Android 10 i have implmented Scoped Storage / Shared Storage concept to share the recordings inside Music folder alone.

My aplication is targeting Android 11 and above so i can't use **requestlegacyexternalstorage**

I have tried to save the Recordings inside this path /storage/emulated/0/Music and it is working fine for Android 11 and above but while i try to write file in Android 10 alone am facing this issue **can't open output file permission denied** but it is working fine on Android 11 and above though

I don't know what needs to be done in Android 10 alone specifically. Anything am missing or suggestions !

Comment: You should try `requestlegacyexternalstorage` for `android 10` and `implement` `scoped storage/shared storage` concept for `android 11` and above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add requestLegacyExternalStorage=true in AndroiManifest.xml with Application tag to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you i thought Android 10 also uses Scoped storage